# Как найти точки пересечения прямых?

Tags: геометрия, three.js

Известны координаты точек: "A", "B", "S". К отрезкам AB и BS построены перпендикуляры и на них от точек A и S найдены точки "с", "d", "u", "v";

Как теперь найти точки: f, e, которые лежат на пересечении прямых, параллельных AB и BS?

Расстояния между точками должны быть равны: Ac = Ad = Sv = Su.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно про `плоскости x и z` писать, это ни к чему. Вы случайно не "толстую линию" хотите нарисовать?

Comment: правки внесены, надеюсь всё максимально понятно :)

Comment: @Эникейщик неизвестны только точки "f" и "e"

Comment: Вам надо уточнить, по какому алгоритму вы их хотите найти - это не так тривиально как вам кажется (например, если прямые cd и uv будут перпендикулярны, или точка B будет левее точки A). Да и название вопроса не отражает его суть ...

Comment: @Kromster данное условие можно решить в несколько довольно простых действий, необходимо рассмотреть данный конкретный случай, указанный на рисунке выше

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140671/discussion-between-leobuildru-and-kromster).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи потребуется выстроить от середины отрезка AB ещë один перпендикуляр, которыц будет задавать направление функции вычисления координат пересечения второй линии по другую сторону

```
function calculateIntersection_sec(p1, p2, p3, p4) {

                    var c2x = p3.x - p4.x; // (x3 - x4)
                    var c3x = p1.x - p2.x; // (x1 - x2)
                    var c2z = p3.z - p4.z; // (y3 - y4)
                    var c3z = p1.z - p2.z; // (y1 - y2)
                  
                    // down part of intersection point formula
                    var d  = c3x * c2z - c3z * c2x;
                  
                    if (d == 0) {
                      throw new Error('Number of intersection points is zero or infinity.');
                    }
                  
                    // upper part of intersection point formula
                    var u1 = p1.x * p2.z - p1.z * p2.x; // (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2)
                    var u4 = p3.x * p4.z - p3.z * p4.x; // (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)
                  
                    // intersection point formula
                    
                    var px = (u1 * c2x - c3x * u4) / d;
                    var pz = (u1 * c2z - c3z * u4) / d;
                    
                    var p = { x: px, z: pz };
                  
                    return p;
                  }
                  
                  
                  // Usage example:
                  
                  // line 1
                  var p1 = { x:  new_it_1, z:  new_it_2 }; // P1: (x1, y1)
                  var p2 = { x:  new_it_3, z:  new_it_4 }; // P2: (x2, y2)
                  
                  // line 2
                  var p3 = { x:  new_it_5, z:  new_it_6 }; // P3: (x4, y4)
                  var p4 = { x:  new_it_7, z:  new_it_8 }; // P4: (x4, y4)
                  
                  var p = calculateIntersection_sec(p1, p2, p3, p4);  // intersection point

                  cube_set_pos_projecct_12.position.x = p.x;
                  cube_set_pos_projecct_12.position.z = p.z;
```

Comment: Люди старались, давали Вам правильные ответы по существу, а вы постите простынку невнятного кода с кубами и отмечаете принятым .. Некрасиво.

Comment: @Kromster так здесь и были учтены все пункты до этого, я премного благодарен, всем кто помогал и вот что у меня получилось, да, код сырой, зато выполняет поставленную задачу

Comment: @Kromster а сейчас я переоформил ответ, здесь по двум точкам задаётся направление, и вычисляется точка пересечения, ответ считаю вполне благоразумным :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Найти величину угла, образованного векторами *BA* и *BS* (привести к диапазону *[0, 2Pi]*)
2. Поделить пополам
3. Нормализовать вектор *BA* и повернуть на угол (*2*)
4. Поделить половину ширины полосы на косинус ( (*2*) - 90 градусов )
5. Задать вектору (*3*) длину (*4*)

Мы нашли *f*

Чтобы найти *е* нужно *f * -1*

Прибавим *B* к *f* и *e* - точки найдены.

Пример:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enablePan = false;

let helper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10, 0x808080, 0x404040);
helper.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5;
helper.position.z = -.001;
scene.add(helper);

const desiredWidth = 1.5;

let ptsBase = [
  /*
  new THREE.Vector2(-3, 1), //A
  new THREE.Vector2(0, 1),  //B
  new THREE.Vector2(4, -3)  //S
  */
  new THREE.Vector2(-3, -3), //A
  new THREE.Vector2(0, 1),  //B
  new THREE.Vector2(4, -3)  //S 
];

let lineBase = new THREE.Line(
  new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(ptsBase),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: "yellow" })
);
scene.add(lineBase);

// all the magic is here //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
let a = new THREE.Vector2().subVectors(ptsBase[0], ptsBase[1]); //BA
let b = new THREE.Vector2().subVectors(ptsBase[2], ptsBase[1]); //BS
let angle = (Math.PI - b.angle()) - (Math.PI - a.angle()); // [0..PI2]

let halfAngle = angle * 0.5;
let scaleVal = Math.cos(Math.abs(halfAngle - (Math.PI * 0.5)));
let f = a
  .clone()
  .setLength(desiredWidth / scaleVal)
  .rotateAround(new THREE.Vector2(), -halfAngle);
let e = f.clone().negate();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let cornerLine = new THREE.Line(
  new THREE.BufferGeometry()
    .setFromPoints([f.clone().add(ptsBase[1]), e.clone().add(ptsBase[1])])
    .setAttribute(
      "color",
      new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 3)
    ),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: true })
);
scene.add(cornerLine);

let lineTop = new THREE.Line(
  new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(
    ptsBase.map((p) => {
      return p.clone().add(f);
    })
  ),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ffff })
);
let lineBottom = new THREE.Line(
  new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(
    ptsBase.map((p) => {
      return p.clone().add(e);
    })
  ),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 })
);
scene.add(lineTop, lineBottom);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

</script>
```

Comment: странная фигня, пишет якобы: app.js:281 Uncaught TypeError: b.angle is not a function

Comment: эта фигня возникает при использовании vector3 заместо vector2, т.к. я хочу использовать систему координат XZ, заместо XY

Comment: крч, вопрос, как это всё сделать на осях xz

Comment: @Leobuildru Смоитри. Есть у нас вектор 1, 1, 0. Поверни его вокруг оси X по часовой стрелке, если смотреть со стороны положительной полуоси X. Какая будет координата у точки теперь? Вот это и есть перевод из XY в XZ. По большому счету даже поворачивать не надо - просто Y умножай на -1, записывай в Z. Новые координаты точки у нас получатся 1, 0, -1. Про это я даже в ответе на предыдущий вопрос писал. Но кто ж это читал )

Comment: Я прост не вдупляю, можешь пж на примере показать, как эту тему делать? Буду крайне благодарен, у меня на теории не оч заходит, а когда есть реальный видимый пример, то становится гораздо понятнее.

Comment: @Kromster можешь пожалуйста показать на коде, про что он говорит :)

Comment: можете пожалуйста объяснить, что делает данная строка: let angle = (Math.PI - b.angle()) - (Math.PI - a.angle()); // [0..PI2]

Comment: @Leobuildru вычисляет угол между векторами в диапазоне от 0 до 360 градусов (от 0 до 2Пи), если я сам правильно понимаю )

Comment: можно ли это считать за правду в трёхмерном пространстве?
let a = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(ptsBase[0], ptsBase[1]); //BA
let b = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(ptsBase[2], ptsBase[1]);

let angle_pref = a.angleTo(b);
console.log( Math.max( 2*Math.PI - angle_pref, angle_pref ) * 180 / Math.PI );

Comment: и что делает эта строка? let f = a
  .clone()
  .setLength(desiredWidth / scaleVal)
  .rotateAround(new THREE.Vector2(), -halfAngle);

Comment: @Leobuildru При всем уважении, но, работая с определенным фреймворком, можно, наверное, уже почитать про объекты и их методы в документации к фреймворку? Все, что делал в примере - это школьная программа, максимум первый курс техникума. 1) Берешь клонированный вектор BA, 2)делишь половину ширины полосы на косинус разности половины вычисленного угла и 90 градусов (Пи пополам) (знак разности не важен, можешь взять по модулю), этим находишь длину поворачиваемого вектора, коею и устанавливаешь (через `setLength()`), 3) поворачиваешь его (вектор BA) на половину вычисленного угла (`rotateAround()`).

Comment: прошу прощения, а где собственно команда вывода точек пересечения прямых? в вопросе указывалось о нахождении точек, то-есть их координат

Comment: @Leobuildru Не ленись, посмотри - как пользоваться `console.log()`. Не забудь только к клонированным `f` и `e` прибавить `ptsBase[1]` (она же точка `B`), ибо все ищется относительно нее. PS Не стесняйся задавать вопросы на форуме и в дискорде (все ссылки есть в описании к тегу three.js)

Comment: `let angle = (Math.PI - b.angle()) - (Math.PI - a.angle());` после сокращений переходит в `let angle = a.angle() - b.angle();`

Answer (score 3):

Функция `thickLine` принимает координаты трёх точек и смещение, возвращает координаты трёх пар точек: левая и правая соседки для первой точки, левая и правая соседки для второй точки, левая и правая соседки для третьей точки.

Математика для крайних точек простая: направление отрезка поворачивается на девяносто градусов (***(x, y) -> (-y, x)***), длина нормализуется. Имея направление легко вычислить соседок точек.

Поворот вектора ***v*** обозначим как ***v<sup>^</sup>***. Тогда левая соседка точки
***a*** относительно отрезка ***(a, b)*** на расстоянии ***w*** будет:

***n<sub>a</sub> = (b - a)<sup>^</sup>*** - нормаль к отрезку.

***a<sub>l</sub> = a + w n<sub>a</sub>*** - левая соседка.

Левая соседка точки ***c*** относительно отрезка ***(b, c)***:

***n<sub>c</sub> = (c - b)<sup>^</sup>*** - нормаль к отрезку.

***c<sub>l</sub> = c + w n<sub>c</sub>*** - левая соседка.

Левая соседка точки ***b***. Направление в котором нужно двигаться вычисляется
как биссектриса направлений ***n<sub>a</sub>*** и ***n<sub>c</sub>***:

***n<sub>b</sub> = n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>c</sub>***.

Сама левая соседка:

***b<sub>l</sub> = b + (2 w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) n<sub>b</sub>***.

Покажем что отрезок ***(a<sub>l</sub>, b<sub>l</sub>)*** параллелен ***(a,
b)***. Для этого он должен быть перпендикулярен ***n<sub>a</sub>***, то есть
надо проверить что скалярное произведение равно нулю:

***n<sub>a</sub> (b<sub>l</sub> - a<sub>l</sub>) =***

***= n<sub>a</sub> (b + (2 w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) n<sub>b</sub> - (a + w n<sub>a</sub>)) =***

***= n<sub>a</sub> ((b - a) + (2 w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) n<sub>b</sub> - w n<sub>a</sub>) =***

***= n<sub>a</sub> (b - a) + n<sub>a</sub> ((2 w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) n<sub>b</sub> - w n<sub>a</sub>) =***

***= 0 + n<sub>a</sub> (w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) (2 n<sub>b</sub> - ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup> n<sub>a</sub>) =***

***= n<sub>a</sub> (w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) (2 (n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>c</sub>) - ‖n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>c</sub>‖<sup>2</sup> n<sub>a</sub>) =***

***= (w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) (2 (n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>c</sub>) - ‖n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>c</sub>‖<sup>2</sup> n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>a</sub>) =***

***= (w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) (2 (n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>c</sub>) - ((n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>c</sub>) (n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>c</sub>)) n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>a</sub>) =***

***= (w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) (2 (1 + n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>c</sub>) - (n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>c</sub>) (n<sub>a</sub> + n<sub>c</sub>)) =***

***= (w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) (2 (1 + n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>c</sub>) - (n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>a</sub> + 2 n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>c</sub> + n<sub>c</sub> n<sub>c</sub>)) =***

***= (w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) (2 (1 + n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>c</sub>) - (1 + 2 n<sub>a</sub> n<sub>c</sub> + 1)) =***

***= (w / ‖n<sub>b</sub>‖<sup>2</sup>) 0 =***

***= 0***

Никакой тригонометрии не нужно. Самые сложные операции - деление и извлечение корня. Код может выдавать бесконечности  и `NaN` если точки совпадают или поворот на 180 градусов. В таких ситуациях задача неразрешима в принципе - нельзя определить нормали к отрезкам или определить места средних соседок:

```
// a, b, c - points, w - half width
const thickLine = (a, b, c, w) => {

    const normal = (a, b) => {
        const x = b[0] - a[0];
        const y = b[1] - a[1];
        const f = 1 / Math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2);
        return [-y * f, x * f];
    };

    const na = normal(a, b);
    const nc = normal(b, c);

    const d = [na[0] + nc[0], na[1] + nc[1]];
    const f = w * 2 / (d[0] ** 2 + d[1] ** 2);

    const shift = (p, dir, w) => [
        p[0] + dir[0] * w, p[1] + dir[1] * w
    ];

    return [
        shift(a, na,  w),
        shift(a, na, -w),
        shift(b, d ,  f),
        shift(b, d , -f),
        shift(c, nc,  w),
        shift(c, nc, -w)
    ];
};
```

Полный работающий пример. Красные точки можно таскать:

```js
// a, b, c - points, w - half width
const thickLine = (a, b, c, w) => {

    const normal = (a, b) => {
        const x = b[0] - a[0];
        const y = b[1] - a[1];
        const f = 1 / Math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2);
        return [-y * f, x * f];
    };

    const na = normal(a, b);
    const nc = normal(b, c);

    const d = [na[0] + nc[0], na[1] + nc[1]];
    const f = w * 2 / (d[0] ** 2 + d[1] ** 2);

    const shift = (p, dir, w) => [
        p[0] + dir[0] * w, p[1] + dir[1] * w
    ];

    return [
        shift(a, na,  w),
        shift(a, na, -w),
        shift(b, d ,  f),
        shift(b, d , -f),
        shift(c, nc,  w),
        shift(c, nc, -w)
    ];
};

const makePoint = svg => {
    const point = document.createElementNS(
        'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'circle'
    );
    point.setAttribute('r', 4);
    point.setAttribute('stroke', 'blue');
    point.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
    svg.appendChild(point);

    const movePoint = (x, y) => {
        if (!isFinite(x) || !isFinite(y)) {
            return;
        }
        const ctm = point.getCTM();
        ctm.e = x;
        ctm.f = y;

        const t = svg.createSVGTransform();
        t.setMatrix(ctm);

        point.transform.baseVal.initialize(t);
    };

    return {
        'move': movePoint
    };
};

const makeDraggablePoint = svg => {
    const subscribers = [];

    const group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
    svg.appendChild(group);

    const p = () => {
        const ctm = group.getCTM();
        return [ctm.e, ctm.f];
    };

    const moveGroup = (x, y) => {
        const ctm = group.getCTM();
        ctm.e = x;
        ctm.f = y;

        const t = svg.createSVGTransform();
        t.setMatrix(ctm);

        group.transform.baseVal.initialize(t);

        subscribers.forEach(e => e());
    };

    const handle = document.createElementNS(
        'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'circle'
    );

    handle.setAttribute('r', 20);
    handle.setAttribute('stroke', 'transparent');
    handle.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
    handle.style.cursor = 'grab';
    group.appendChild(handle);
                    
    const point = document.createElementNS(
        'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'circle'
    );
    point.setAttribute('r', 4);
    point.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
    point.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
    point.style.cursor = 'grab';
    group.appendChild(point);

    const onPointerDown = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const [x, y] = p();
        const offset_x = x - e.clientX;
        const offset_y = y - e.clientY;
        group.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);

        const oldMove = group.onpointermove;
        const oldUp = group.onpointerup;

        group.onpointermove = e => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const sx = e.clientX + offset_x;
            const sy = e.clientY + offset_y;
            moveGroup(sx, sy);
        };

        group.onpointerup = e => {
            e.preventDefault();

            group.onpointerup = oldUp;
            group.onpointermove = oldMove;
            group.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
        };
    };

    handle.onpointerdown = onPointerDown;
    point.onpointerdown = onPointerDown;


    return {
        'subscribe': cb => subscribers.push(cb),
        'p': p,
        'move': moveGroup,
    };
};

const makeSegment = svg => {
    // <line x1="10" x2="50" y1="110" y2="150" stroke="orange" stroke-width="5"/>
    const line = document.createElementNS(
        'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'line'
    );
    svg.appendChild(line);

    line.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
    line.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');

    return {
        'p1': () => [line.getAttribute('x1'), line.getAttribute('y1')],
        'p2': () => [line.getAttribute('x2'), line.getAttribute('y2')],
        'move1': (x, y) => {
            if (isFinite(x) && isFinite(y)) {
                line.setAttribute('x1', x);
                line.setAttribute('y1', y);
            }
        },
        'move2': (x, y) => {
            if (isFinite(x) && isFinite(y)) {
                line.setAttribute('x2', x);
                line.setAttribute('y2', y);
            }
        }
    };
};

(() => {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    const svg = document.createElementNS(
        'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'svg'
    );
    svg.setAttribute('width', 400);
    svg.setAttribute('height', 200);
    body.appendChild(svg);

    const s12 = makeSegment(svg);
    const s23 = makeSegment(svg);

    const s12l = makeSegment(svg);
    const s12r = makeSegment(svg);

    const s23l = makeSegment(svg);
    const s23r = makeSegment(svg);

    const p1l = makePoint(svg);
    const p1r = makePoint(svg);

    const p2l = makePoint(svg);
    const p2r = makePoint(svg);

    const p3l = makePoint(svg);
    const p3r = makePoint(svg);

    const p1 = makeDraggablePoint(svg);
    const p2 = makeDraggablePoint(svg);
    const p3 = makeDraggablePoint(svg);

    const halfWidth = 20;

    const updateLine = () => {
        const points = thickLine(p1.p(), p2.p(), p3.p(), halfWidth);

        p1l .move (...points[0]);
        s12l.move1(...points[0]);

        p1r .move (...points[1]);
        s12r.move1(...points[1]);

        p2l .move (...points[2]);
        s12l.move2(...points[2]);
        s23l.move1(...points[2]);

        p2r .move (...points[3]);
        s12r.move2(...points[3]);
        s23r.move1(...points[3]);

        p3l .move (...points[4]);
        s23l.move2(...points[4]);

        p3r .move (...points[5]);
        s23r.move2(...points[5]);
    };

    p1.subscribe(() => {
        s12.move1(...p1.p());
        updateLine();
    });

    p2.subscribe(() => {
        const [x, y] = p2.p();
        s12.move2(x, y);
        s23.move1(x, y);
        updateLine();
    });

    p3.subscribe(() => {
        s23.move2(...p3.p());
        updateLine();
    });

    p1.move(100, 50);
    p2.move(200, 50);
    p3.move(200, 100);
})();
```

Comment: это кнч афигенский ответ, честно, я ценю и уважаю ваш труд, но было б ваще без б если бы данный пример был без isdragble и сделан на осях XZ

Comment: можете пожалуйста в первом отрывке кода прописать документацию к нему по типу к каждой строке добавить: //делаем то-то, то-то
буду крайне благодарен.

Comment: Весь код кроме `thickLine` - демонстрация для вау-эффекта. Вам интересна только математика `thickLine`. Я её распишу подробнее. Переделку в оси XZ оставляю вам - это чисто механическая работа. Вы можете сделать её двумя способами. Первый - изменить саму функцию, там только индексы и создание новых точек в `shift`. Второй - обернуть функцию в обёртку, которая параметры проецирует на плоскость, а результаты поднимает в пространство.